# How to duplicate a sprite in sprite kit and have them behave differently

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I've been working on a IOS mobile game and I wanted to take an object,duplicate it, and have the copies move all over the screen. I've looked through Google to find things relevant to this but they were all in Objective C or just didn't have what I was looking for. I want to know how to do this in Swift and SpriteKit.

Comment: To "spawn" in iOS spriteKit, you basically `.copy()` as Dion describes below.

Answer (score 14):

If you are working with `SKSpriteNode` you can copy it and all it's current properties with:

```
let copiedNode = nodeToCopy.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
```

You will still need need to add `copiedNode` to your scene. `copiedNode` will also continue to run any actions that `nodeToCopy` was running. You can cancel them with `copiedNode.removeAllActions()`.

---

Note that the documentation for the protocol `NSCopying` reads exactly:

> Protocol
>
> **NSCopying**
>
> A protocol that objects adopt to provide functional
>   copies of themselves.
>
> The exact meaning of “copy” can vary from class to class, but a copy
>   must be a functionally independent object with values identical to the
>   original at the time the copy was made...

Indeed, in the case of `SKSpriteNode`, Apple have interpreted that idea so that the `copy()` function "spawns" another instance of the item, **exactly as in any game engine**.

(So, for SKSpriteNode copy() works identically to the sense of `Instantiate` in Unity, say.)

As mogelbuster points out below, there is nowhere in the Apple documentation that they state *"The spawn command in Apple is copy()"* but in fact they have interpreted this "The exact meaning of “copy” can vary from class to class" in exactly that way for SKNode, since indeed it's a game engine and it's the only meaningful sense of copy there.

---

It's worth noting that the most completely typical way to work in games is: for your say rocketShips, you would have one "model" of your rocketShip, say modelRocketShip. **The model simply sits offscreen**, or is perhaps marked as invisible or inactive. You never use the model in the game, it just sits there. When you spawn rocketShips, you just dupe the model.  (So in Apple that's modelRocketShip.copy() and then set the position etc.)

Comment: When i use let copiedNode = nodeToCopy.copy() as! SKSpriteNode I get an error saying use of unresolved identifier nodeToCopy

Comment: That code is generalized. `nodeToCopy` represents the node that you want to take a copy of.

Comment: Will I need to set a new position for the copied nodes so that the original and multiple copies I plan on making won't overlap?

Comment: The position gets copied with `copy` so yes, you will need to set a new one or the node will be in the same position. `copiedNode` will also need to be added to your scene.

Comment: I want to have 14 of the same node  that float around in different directions. Does this mean i need to repeat the code you showed above 14 times? Or is there a way to make write a method that repeats/cycles 14 times?

Comment: @kaptainken Use loops for that. You should really start with basics of programming before you jump into more complex stuff like game development.

Comment: How do you associate actions with a node so they they're copied when the node is copied? I'm only familiar with nodeName.runAction(etc...) which is specific to an instance, not associated, so far as I know.

Comment: Where in the documentation does it say `copy()` works with `SKSpriteNode`?  I mean I know that `SKSpriteNode` inherits from `SKNode` which conforms to `NSCopying`, but I don't see anywhere that says `SKSpriteNode` has a custom implementation for `copy()`.  I found this on `NSCopying` docs: "If a subclass inherits NSCopying from its superclass and declares additional instance variables, the subclass has to override copy(with:) to properly handle its own instance variables, invoking the superclass’s implementation first."  So I know it must override copy I just can't find documentation about it.

Comment: @mogelbuster I attempted to address your interesting question in the answer, cheers.

Comment: It's good to note that using copy doesn't copy the physics bodies properties like angular/linear damping

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function to create and return a sprite :

```
func createSprite()->SKSpriteNode{
    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(...)//Use the init function in the SKSpriteNode class
    //Add some code to define the sprite's property
    return sprite
}
```

And call this function to get some sprites that have the same property:

```
let spriteOne = createSprite() 
let spriteTwo = createSprite()
```

Then you can add different `SKAction`s to each of them so that they can behave differently.

Comment: So this is generally how I program this kind of action.  Do you think it would be better/more efficient to create a clone of the same node if they are all going to perform the same action anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have multiple SKSpriteNodes, you can also control them by using `EnumerateChildNodesWithName` (assuming all your nodes have the same name) to go through all of them do do what you want in the update() function.

On a more advanced level, you could subclass SKSpriteNode and incorporate your own behaviour in your custom class.