# Adding multiple of the same SKSpriteNode() in swift 4.0

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I know this question has been asked multiple times but I have looked online forever and cannot find the solution to my basic problem.

I have a `SKPhysicsContact` that runs the following code when 2 objects come in contact:

```
let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "circle")
            ball.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width / 3, y: self.frame.size.height / 3)
            ball.size = CGSize(width: ballSize * 2, height: ballSize * 2)
            ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ballSize)
            ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
            ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
            ball.physicsBody?.linearDamping =  0
            ball.physicsBody?.friction = 0
            ball.zPosition = 2
            ball.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategoryBall
            ball.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategoryAll
            ball.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategoryWall
            ball.run(colorBlack)
            self.addChild(ball)
```

The first time the `SKPhysicsContact` code runs, `SKSpriteNode` "ball" is created. Obviously the 2nd time the `SKPhysicsContact` runs, the game crashes because it is trying to add "ball" again when "ball" already exists.

Without `removeFromParent()` on ball before adding another ball, how do I create a simple func / way to create the same `SKSpriteNode` "ball" over and over each time I run my `SKPhysicsContact`?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't create the node upon contact; instead, make it somewhere else (Upon initialization of all entities, or such). Have you tried making a deep copy out of it, and then using the copy?
E.G

```
   let spriteCopy = spriteNode.copy() as SKSpriteNode
```

For further info, check out [How to duplicate a sprite in sprite kit and have them behave differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36073940/how-to-duplicate-a-sprite-in-sprite-kit-and-have-them-behave-differently)

Comment: Thanks! After a bit of research with your .copy() i figured it out. I made a node then used the .copy() function in the SKPhysicsContact part. Cheers :)